# Reset python iterator when I get value

Tags: python

If I got like 10, 50, 100, 120, 140, 160, 100, 50 this code:

```html
mock_len = len(db)
epsilon = 20
max_data = 0
for i in range(mock_len - 1):
    if db[i+1][0]-db[i][0] == 20:
        max_data = db[i+1]

        print max_data
```

will print 120,140,160, but I only want to print 1 value, in my case 120, how do I reset to 0 the max_data var when I get a value in order to contue to compare in the loop.

Let's say I get to 120, get the 120 to max_data initial var, the reset the max_data to 0 and continue comparing. I have a bigger list of data where I want only 1 value when I encounter 20 diff.

Comment: At first I thought, well, simply move `print max_data` to the beginning of the line (i.e., remove the indentation)... But then I realized that your question was as clear as a smoggy day in New Delhi!!!

Comment: it is very unclear to me what it is that you are asking and what the problem is. But it looks like it should be easily explainable..

Comment: Pleas let us know what is `db`?

Answer (score 0):

As i said in the comments, your querstion is very unclear. But below is my longshot attempt.

```
db = [10, 50, 100, 120, 140, 160, 100, 50]
g = [db[i] for i, _ in enumerate(db) if db[i]-db[i-1] == 20]
print(g)     # [120, 140, 160] :prints all instances where the difference is 20
print(g[0])  #            120  :prints the first instance where the difference is 20
```

You do not need to reset anything to get the first instance of something. Alternatively, if you only want the first one and don't want to find them all you can use a `while` loop. I will let you write that on your own though.